# Chrome.identity getAuthToken callback not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm building a chrome extension, in which I utilize the google calendar api to programmatically create a calendar by **scraping** a webpage.  The flow is as such.

User clicks Button in pop-up window
If already authenticated then it scrapes the page and correctly creates the calender.
If not authenticated, then a pop up shows up asking the user to login. After the user logs in and authenticates, a call back function SHOULD be fired which then proceeds with scraping the page.

The call back is not firing, and to get the call back to be called, a subsequent click of the button is required.

Here is my getAuthTokenCall:

```
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      let init = {
        method: "POST",
        async: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          summary: "2021-2022 Academic Year",
        }),
        contentType: "json",
      };
      fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars", init)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.status == 401) {
            console.log("the response was 401");
            chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
              { token: token },
              function () {
                // This forces a rerun of the funciton
                createCalender();
              }
            );
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
          chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
            tabs.forEach((tab) => {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, data.id);
            });
          });
        });
    });
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "DraftToCalender",
"description": "Taking draft my sched and adding classes to Google calender",
"version": "0.1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"key": "big key here",
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "google o-auth client key here",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    ]
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js; object-src 'self'",

"icons": {
    "16": "./obj-16x16.png",
    "32": "./obj-32x32.png",
    "48": "./obj-48x48.png",
    "128": "./obj-128x128.png"
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "script1"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://draftmyschedule.uwo.ca/secure/builder.cfm"
        ],
        "js": [
           "content.js"
        ]
    }
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "blahblah",
    "default_popup": "./index.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
]
```

}